# Xtext cross-references work only with an Xtext Java Project?

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

I followed this tutorial [Second Iteration: Adding Packages and Imports](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html#add-imports) by [Xtext](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/). I was trying to make a cross reference like the one shown in the last picture of the tutorial, that I paste here:
[image: Xtext Tutorial]

In first example of the tutorial page I had simply to create a java project and a file `mymodel.dmodel` and everything works fine.

I noticed that in second example (named `Second Iteration: Adding Packages and Imports`) the cross-references don't work (I have some `Could'nt resolve reference` errors) with a simple java project.
However it works fine if I convert the project to an `Xtext project`.

Is this a normal behaviour or have I missed some configuration steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the cross references work you need

1. A project with xtext nature + builder (that is what convert to xtext project does, this is an "add xtext" not a "remove java" operation
2. Build automatically should be enabled
3. Depending on the project type

   1. Java Project: Put the files in a source folder
   2. Non Java (General -> Project): Put the files anywhere